# Linq expression with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a linq expression that I want to group and and cast as hard type `List<DocumentGroup>`

This linq query works correctly:

```
var DocumentGroups = (from dt in DocumentTypes
                       let dg = dt.DocumentGroup
                       select new DocumentGroup(){
                           Name = dg.Namn, 
                           Id = dg.Id
                        }).GroupBy(group => group.Id).ToList();
```

Now I want do the same query and cast it to a `List<DocumentGroup>` but I receive this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping[System.Guid,ConsoleApplication1+DocumentGroup]' to type 'DocumentGroup'.

```
List<DocumentGroup> DocumentGroups = (from dt in DocumentTypes
                           let dg = dt.DocumentGroup
                           select new DocumentGroup(){
                               Name = dg.Namn,
                               Id = dg.Id
                           }).GroupBy(group => group.Id).Cast<DocumentGroup>.ToList();
```

If I remove `.GroupBy(group => group.Id)` from the linq expression, it works correctly, but I need the group expression to filter it out. How can I make this work?

The DocumentGroup class

```
public class DocumentGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you group by `Id` then you have no access to `Name` outside of an aggregation. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `GroupBy` you get groups. So casting a group to a single item will fail.

If all you want to do is remove duplicates then you can select the first item from each group:

```
var DocumentGroups = (from dt in DocumentTypes
                      let dg = dt.DocumentGroup
                      select new DocumentGroup() 
                             { 
                                Name = dg.Namn, 
                                Id = dg.Id 
                             }).GroupBy(group => group.Id)
                               .Select(g => g.First())
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: Wonderful. Now it works and I have access to Name also? :)
Can you explain what I did wrong?

Comment: @user3046164 when you use groupby you have groups, for example you get a `IGrouping<T, K>` where `T` is the type of Key, and `K` is the type of your values.This is a group, not a single item.there can be more than one item under the group, right? that is the purpose of grouping. you tried to cast a group to a single item directly like casting a list of Foos to a single Foo that's why it failed

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the `GroupBy` you have a list of `DocumentGroup` (like single dimensional array)

```
1    Name1       <record 1 of DocumentGroup>
1    Name2       <record 2 of DocumentGroup>
1    Name3       <record 3 of DocumentGroup>
2    Name4       <record 4 of DocumentGroup>
3    Name5       <record 5 of DocumentGroup>
```

After doing the `GroupBy` you have a list of `IGrouping<int, DocumentGroup>` (like a two dimensional array)

```
1    1    Name1       --|
     1    Name2         -- <record 1 of IGrouping<int, DocumentGroup>
     1    Name3       --|
2    2    Name4            <record 2 of IGrouping<int, DocumentGroup>>
3    3    Name5            <record 3 of IGrouping<int, DocumentGroup>>
```

So to get the `DocumentGroup` you need to access from the `Grouping` item first, then you get the `DocumentGroup`, example:

```
var groupOfDocumentGroups = /* omitted code */
     select new DocumentGroup() { Name = dg.Namn, Id = dg.Id })
     .GroupBy(group => group.Id)
     .ToList();

foreach(var groupItem in groupOfDocumentGroups)
{
    // groupItem type is IGrouping<int, DocumentGroup>
    // groupItem has `Key` property which is an integer of the Id.
    // groupItem is also a collection that you can do enumeration.
    foreach(var item in groupItem)
    {
        // there you go, item type is DocumentGroup
    }
}
```

> but I must have the group expression to filter it out

I assume you want to get all unique `DocumentGroup`s in all `DocumentType`s, then `Salman22` answer is what you're looking for.

You can also use `Distinct` in this case. If you're working with linq to entities, you can just have.

```
var documentGroups = context.DocumentTypes
    .Select(x => x.DocumentGroup)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

If you're working with linq to object, you can implement `IEqualityComparer<DocumentGroup>` first.

```
class DocumentGroupComparer : IEqualityComparer<DocumentGroup>
{
    public bool Equals(DocumentGroupx, DocumentGroupy)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(DocumentGroup obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

var documentGroups = DocumentTypes
    .Select(x => x.DocumentGroup)
    .Distinct(new DocumentGroupComparer())
    .ToList();
```